# Javascript always thinking my IFrame content & size are empty, but it isn't - Trying to resize IFrame to injected content automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So I have been struggling with this for hours now, and all the relevant results I found indicated my code is correct, but clearly It isn't, as it doesn't work.

Ultimately what I am trying to do is jsut resize an IFrame height to match it's content(with 100px minimum). Note: Iframe35382-content will be generated via the backend, hence this approach to populating the IFrame.

The code correctly populates the IFrame with the data I want, and resizes it, but for some reason I am clearly missing the contents height is always returned as 150px(which I understand is the default height of an IFrame) and the html returned by contents().find('html') - used to dump the content of the IFrame - that I spit out for debugging purposes is always undefined.

Any help or direction appreciated, probably just need a second set of eyes to spot something silly ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Relevant Code below :

```
<iframe id="Iframe35382" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script id="Iframe35382-content" type="text/plain">
<html>
<head>
<p>Lengthy html(correctly displaying) shortened for porposes of question</p>
</body>
</html>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckIFrameHeight($frame)
{
  var newHeight = $frame.contents().height();
  alert(newHeight); // DEBUG
  alert($frame.contents().find('html').html()); // DEBUG
  if(!newHeight || isNaN(newHeight))
    newHeight = 100;
  $frame.height(newHeight + 'px');
}
var iframe = document.getElementById('Iframe35382');
iframe.src = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent($('#Iframe35382-content').text());
CheckIFrameHeight($('#Iframe35382'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I discovered that the issue was down to the way the code is injectd into the frame using :

```
data:text/html, [...]
```

Despite this being the recommended way of doing so i found on Stackoverflow, it appears to break IFrame origin checks, using a different method to populate the IFrame solved all the issues, namely writing directly to the IFrame document.

```
// Remove this line
iframe.src = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent($('#Iframe35382-content').text());

// Replace with these
var iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument;
if(iframedoc)
{
  iframedoc.open();
  iframedoc.writeln($('#Iframe35382-content').text());
  iframedoc.close();
 }
```

This means the src atrtibute is no longer used - at all, and both contents() and height() are correctly returned, allowing me to resize the IFrame to it's contents.